# Scrape hidden iframe without using selenium

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wanted to try and extract a certain video in this form

[image]

in https://www.cultura.com/marvel-s-spider-man-0711719416470.html. I did inspect and tried to find the video src in order to get the video. However, I'm confused how to do it, Since the video can only be found via the API using inspect element  -> network->under XHR which is https://cdmc.cedemo.com/vdo/66634/66634_1500.mp4?md5=aqSi-RgcFGqVkMABnnpzAQ&expires=1555432233.

What I did was try find via soup the video id.

```
import requests

video = requests.get(soup.find("videoId")["src"])
```

In this case it returns `403`, which tells me that it was not subscriptable. Anybody knows how to solve this case?